# Seeking less costly design than using nested IF...ELSE in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am allowing a user to create their own SELECT statements using 3 dropdowns in a view. These dropdowns will generate the SQL in the `WHERE` clause. For example: `WHERE StatusId > 6`. The middle dropdown is used to select the operator, in which there are 6 options: `=, >, >=, <, <=, LIKE`. I am trying to avoid dynamic SQL as to protect from injection.

So here is the SQL code (in a SP) that is called when a user makes a selection:

```
    If @topOperatorInput  = '=' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedColumns
    from ReturnAuthorization
    where @topLeftInput = @topRightInput;
  End
  Else If @topOperatorInput  = '>' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedColumns
    from ReturnAuthorization
    where @topLeftInput > @topRightInput;
  End
  Else If @topOperatorInput  = '>=' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedColumns
    from ReturnAuthorization
    where @topLeftInput >= @topRightInput;
 End
  Else If @selectedColumns  = '<' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedColumns
    from ReturnAuthorization
    where @topLeftInput < @topRightInput;
  End
  Else If @topOperatorInput  = '<=' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedColumns
    from ReturnAuthorization
    where @topLeftInput <= @topRightInput;
  End
  Else If @topOperatorInput  = 'LIKE' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedColumns
    from ReturnAuthorization
    where @topLeftInput LIKE @topRightInput;
  End
```

All the variables you see here are input variables (user selections) coming in from an MVC Controller.

Here's where things get a little tricky for me. The user can select an `AND` option, where they can add 3 more dropdowns to the page to select from.

For example: `WHERE StatusId > 6 AND UserId = 2`

Now, the new operator dropdown adds another 6 choices into the mix. To accommodate, if I keep this current format, I would have to nest 6 IF...ELSE IFs in each of the 6 options shown above.

Any solution for a less costly way to execute this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: little clear `select case when @topOperatorInput '=' then @selectedColumns else null end`

Comment: Sorry? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: You pretty much have to use dynamic sql if either topLeftInput or topRightInput is a column name.  Unless you also want to create IF statements for every possible column the user could choose.

Comment: You should probably also look into sp_executesql. You can use variables with it, so that way you should be able to avoid SQL injection

Comment: dumb question, because I don't know your particular programming environment but could you not build your own sql dynamically, from trusted parts?  i.e. \@to_exec = "Select " + \@selectedColumns + " from xxx where " + @_some_assigned_criteria variable which depends on \@topOperatorInput?  using a case as above?  Key being that you build \@_some_assigned_criteria based on, but not directly using, user input

Comment: I just did something similar to this with an MVC application that basically took user input and constructed a query and passed that data to my controller which in turn did some checks for sql injection stuff and basically used SQLCommand and the connection string to return a datatable which in turn was sent back to a view in tabular format for a user to view. Is that kind of what you're going for here?

Comment: Yeah, using Entity Framework in C# MVC to send their data as input parameters in a stored procedure.

Comment: As this is pretty much a type of catch all query I would suggest you look at this article. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: I have done something similar with dynamic SQL its not bad a few loops and your done, but without it, you have EVERY combination to account for.  If you really must do it without dynamic i would suggest listing all combination in EXCEL then write the formula and drag it down so it write all the code for you.

Comment: Actually, I see no other option but to build your sql in code or using dynamic sql. You can't parameterize column names (or any identifier for that matter). If your users are using dropdowns then you should be able to control the generated sql to protect yourself from sql injection anyway.

Comment: I didn't realize that. There is no way to parametrize column names?

Comment: My reservation against dynamic SQL was due to SQL injection fears, but if it could be executed safely then I would be for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch case , so that it will check the only condition it is needed and swap all the other conditions without checking